# Is there any theoretical difference in performance in an inline constexpr function that compares an `int` & `int` VS a `const char* & `const char*`?

Tags: c++, performance, constexpr

###### Is there any theoretical difference in performance in an `inline constexpr` function that compares an `int` & `int` VS a `const char*` & `const char*`, when optimization is enabled?

Example 1 (`int` equals `int`)

```cpp
struct some_struct {
    int m_type;
    ...
    inline constexpr
    void somefunc() {
        if (m_type == 0) {
            ...
        } else if (m_type == 1) {
            ...
        }
    }
};
```

Example 2 (`const char*` equals `const char*`)

```cpp
struct some_struct {
    const char* m_type;
    ...
    inline constexpr
    void somefunc() {
        if (strcmp(m_type, "some_str_1")) {
            ...
        } else if (strcmp(m_type, "some_str_2")) {
            ...
        }
    }
};
```

### Edit:

As @RichardCritten pointed out, `strcmp` is not a `constexpr` function. Though in my actual code I have a custom `strcmp` function that is a `constexpr` function.

Comment: Not just theoretical. Do you know what `strcmp` does?

Comment: I don't see how `somefunc` can be  `constexpr` as `strcmp` is not `constexpr` see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp

Comment: Yes I do, so without the `constexpr` it would most certainly have a huge difference. But a constexpr computes the operations at compilation time right?

Comment: @Richard You are right, In my code I have a custom strcmp that is a constexpr function.

Comment: @user34534857 No - "_...The constexpr specifier declares that it is __possible__ to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time. Such variables and functions can then be used where only compile time constant expressions are allowed __(provided that appropriate function arguments are given)__...."_  only some paths / argument combinations may be compile time constant.  You need to use the function result where a [Core constant expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) is expected to find out if it is computed at compile time.

Comment: @RichardCritten Okay thanks! This was very helpful, I will check out the cppreference to learn when a constexpr can actually be computed at compilation time.

Comment: @user34534857 Ok, I had the impression you would assume that `strcmp` would only compare pointers, because obviously it will take longer to iterate through the strings than to compare to integers. Since `m_type` is not known at compile time this function can not be computed at compile time :)

Comment: Btw. `constexpr` implies `inline`. Using both is redundant. Furthermore a function defined inside a class definition is also always automatically `inline`. So it is doubly-redundant. As for the question itself, how can "_any theoretical difference in performance_" possible be answered? The functions do completely different things. Depending on what exactly they do a call to one will be faster than the other or the other way around.

Comment: *`constexpr` implies `inline` on functions, not necessarily on variables.

Comment: Why not look at dissassembly code or do some profiling. In the above case, if either a string or an int do, then you probably want to use an `enum` instead which is a compile time name for an numerical value. Something like `enum class Type { something =1, otherthing = 2 };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constexpr functions are computed at compile-time only when required, I mean in constant expression.

So in constant expression, there are no difference in performance at runtime (compilation time might differ).

In non-constant expression, functions are computed at runtime as any regular functions (With as-if rule, optimizer might optimize and return a result computed at compilation, `constexpr` might be a hint for compiler in that regards).

Comment: Okay thanks, but if I understand it correctly the `constexpr` tag is quite useless when you use an optimizer that automically computes the code at compile time where possible? Especially when you take in consideration that some constexpr functions are not even a constant expression?

Comment: @user34534857 no. If you have a context that requires a constant expression, like a template argument, you cannot call a non-constexpr function. `std::array<int, size(n)>` can only work if `n` and `size` are `constexpr` (or `consteval`)

Comment: Agreed, but I meant more like. Why does the compiler not automatically make everything a `constexpr` where possible?

Comment: @user34534857: If you talk actually about `constexpr`, compiler has to follow the standard, and why standard doesn't make everything `constexpr` by default should be a separate dedicated question (if not already existing). If you talk about optimization, compiler already try to do there best to optimize (and it is a hard problem in general case already).

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Can everytghing be done at compile time? Not necessarily. If yes, then of course there will be no difference in runtime.

And for runtime? On some machines and depending on the arictecture a comparison of an `int` and `char*` can be the same.

This can be found out by looking at the assembler code. Still, some CPU internal procedures will also have an impact.

But, comparing an integral type with a C-style character string will rarely have the same performance, because for a string many bytes need to be compared. Also here modern CPU architecury and assembler instructions may help.

My answer to your question, which seemms to be an [x y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), is:

Most likely there is a difference, but it depends . . .